# Как выбрать покупателей, которые купили сразу 2 определенных товара из таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица покупателей и есть таблица товаров, нужно найти покупателей, которые за месяц купили сразу 2 определенные игрушки.
Вот мой нерабочий вариант. Сколько голову не ломала, ничего так и не надумала.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT FIO, Product.name 
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Purchase ON Customer.Customer_key = Purchase.Customer_key 
INNER JOIN Product ON Purchase.Product_key = Product.Product_key 
WHERE Product.name IN("LEGO","Bear" ) 
AND YEAR(Purchase.data) = 2019 
AND month(Purchase.data) = 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FIO, count(distinct Product.name) 
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Purchase 
   ON Customer.Customer_key = Purchase.Customer_key 
INNER JOIN Product 
   ON Purchase.Product_key = Product.Product_key 
WHERE Product.name IN("LEGO","Bear" ) 
   AND YEAR(Purchase.data) = 2019 
   AND month(Purchase.data)=4
group by FIO
having count(distinct Product.name)=2
```